# Is there a Superset API that I can call to manage (add/modify/delete) Users, Roles Permissions in Superset?

Tags: api, apache-superset

That I can use rather than Superset UI to manage such users/roles/permissions? If not, is this in the Roadmap?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is currently only possible through the Superset CLI not through the API.